# Display an ascended value in a combobox on form load in Access (default value)

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba, ms-access-2010, form-load

So on a form I have, I'm using a combobox (unbound), with the row source being linked to `EntryID`, which is being pulled from a different table. Currently, `EntryID` has values 1 to 300, with 1 being the oldest entry and 300 being the newest entry added.

I use the values in the combobox to requery subforms I'm using on this form. Obviously all tables that the subforms reference have the `EntryID` populated on them.

How can I populate the newest value in the combobox on form load? I can sort the values in ascending or descending order, but that is only after you click the down arrow on the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a query for the combo's Row Source, you can do your sorting in the query by adding this after the `WHERE` clause ...

```sql
ORDER BY EntryID DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `UNION` with the value you want to add:

```
SELECT EntryID FROM urTable 

UNION

SELECT (Max(EntryID) + 1) FROM urTable
```